# How do i get desired result by comparing array of object with object in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, data-structures, lookup, reduce

I have below sample data array of object and submittedValue object. The data array of object is constant it won't change but `submitttedValue` object will change as user proceed with the answer. I have put below desired result need to extract from data array of object and submittedValue object. Please help me out if you have any solution for this.

```
const data = [{
  id: "Q1",
  state: "Test 1",
  answers: [
    { id: "Q1A1", text: "Yes" },
    { id: "Q1A2", text: "No" },
  ],
}, {
  id: "Q2",
  state: "Test 2",
  answers: [
    { id: "Q2A1", text: "Yes" },
    { id: "Q2A2", text: "No" },
  ],
}];

const submittedValue = {
  Q1: {
    Q1A1: "Yes",
  },
  Q2: {
    Q2A2: "No",
  },
};
```

How do I get the below desired result by comparing above data array of object with submittedValue object ?

```
// Expected outcome

const result = [
  { state: "Test 1", answer: "Yes" },
  { state: "Test 2", answer: "No" },
];
```

Comment: What did you try? Why are you using 'Yes' and 'No' instead of true and false?

Comment: the desired result i have to display and the data object is coming from backend

Comment: I did not understand the logic of the desired object. Do you need to compare the data object with submittedValue, but which rules? If we have Q2: { Q2A1: "No", Q2A2: "No"}, what will happen?

Comment: Updated the submittedObject, Q1A1 mean Yes is selected for Q1 and only one object will be there in submitted object for the respective Q1 or Q2 it can't have both one

Comment: Thanks everyone who involve in the discussion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the provided data structure, ...

```
const data = [{
  id: 'Q1',
  state: 'Test 1',
  answers: [
    { id: 'Q1A1', text: 'Yes' },
    { id: 'Q1A2', text: 'No' },
  ],
}, {
  id: 'Q2',
  state: 'Test 2',
  answers: [
    { id: 'Q2A1', text: 'Yes' },
    { id: 'Q2A2', text: 'No' },
  ],
}];
```

... the submitted value ...

```
const submittedValue = {
  Q1: { Q1A1: 'Yes' },
  Q2: { Q2A2: 'No' },
};
```

... and the expected result ...

```
const result = [
  { state: 'Test 1', answer: 'Yes' },
  { state: 'Test 2', answer: 'No' },
];
```

... it is obvious that one needs the `data` just for looking up the test name which is a data-item's `state`-value and becomes a result-item's `state`-value as well ... `const result = [ { state: 'Test 1', ... }, ... ];`.

As for any result-item's `answer`-value, it has to be extracted from each related submitted value's single nested property, because in the latter lays the truth and not within the `data` structure.

Thus, in order to come up with the most efficient approach for retrieving any submitted value's test name, one does [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) the `data` array into an object-based lookup-table where one maps its `state`/test-name by its `id` where the latter is the key and the former is the value ... e.g. ...

```
{
  Q1: 'Test 1',
  Q2: 'Test 2',
}
```

The final result then just needs to be [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)ped from the `submittedValue`'s [`entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) array, where each entry-key relates to the result's `state`/test-name value and each entry-value is an object with just a single own property. The property name does not matter for the result-item's `answer`-value will always be the first item of the object's [`values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) array.

Thus an efficient solution can be based on a single `reduce` task for creating the lookup and another single `map` task which already creates the final result ...

```js
const data = [{
  id: 'Q1',
  state: 'Test 1',
  answers: [
    { id: 'Q1A1', text: 'Yes' },
    { id: 'Q1A2', text: 'No' },
  ],
}, {
  id: 'Q2',
  state: 'Test 2',
  answers: [
    { id: 'Q2A1', text: 'Yes' },
    { id: 'Q2A2', text: 'No' },
  ],
}];
const submittedValue = {
  Q1: { Q1A1: 'Yes' },
  Q2: { Q2A2: 'No' },
};

// ... approach / solution ...

const testNameLookup = data
  .reduce((lookup, testItem) => {

    const { id, state } = testItem;
    lookup[id] = state;

    return lookup;
  }, {});

const result = Object
  .entries(submittedValue)
  .map(([ key, value ]) => {

    const state = testNameLookup[key];
    const answer = Object.values(value)[0];

    return { state, answer };
  });

console.log({ result, testNameLookup });
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: ... and the uncommented -1 was earned for exactly which (technical fault) reason? Leaving a comment would help improve both the answer and myself.

Answer (score -1):

```js
const data = [
{
id: 'Q1',
state: 'Test 1',
answers: [{id: "Q1A1", 'text': 'Yes'},{id: "Q1A2", 'text': 'No'}]
},
{
id: 'Q2',
state: 'Test 2',
answers: [{id: "Q2A1", 'text': 'Yes'},{id: "Q2A2", 'text': 'No'}]
},
];

const submittedValue = {
    Q1: {
        Q1A2: "Yes",
    },
    Q2: {
        Q2A2: "No",
    },
};

let result = Object.keys(submittedValue).map((value) => {
  // First let's find correct question inside data
  let currentQuestion = data.find(question => value === question.id)
  
  // Now check for the current answer
  let givenAnswer = submittedValue[value]
  
  // Extract the text from given answer
  let textAnswer = Object.values(givenAnswer)[0]
  
  // Finally return the result
  return {state: currentQuestion.state, answer: textAnswer}
})

console.log(result)
```

Comment: @Raj ... The above approach is the more intuitive one in comparison to the already criticized one of _blakkwater_. Anyhow both implementations have its own flaw. The above one suffers from having to additionally iterate the `data` array via `find` for each processed submitted value item, which for bigger data structures introduces a logarithmic time complexity (growing significantly for real large arrays). And for nitpicking ... if one does `Object.keys(submittedValue)` one does not `.map((value) => { ... })` but one does `.map((key) => { ... })`

Comment: You are completely right about the flaw. However I just want to note that the nitpicking is open for discussion. Because if I use (value,key), the key will be the index and also the real key. So in my opinion I would still use value, but like I already said: I think this is more personal flavor :)